# Thorough understanding of any multi-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a Java beginner and multi-dimensional array questions have been asked before but none of the answers have been clear and concise.

For instance, when a 2-D array is initialized like this:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3}}
```

That simply means the element "1" is "row 1, column 1", element "2" is"row 1, column 2"
but what about

```
int[][][] b = {{1,2,3}}
```

Does that mean element "1" is "1 x, 1 y, 1 z" in the 3-D array b?

What about a multi-dimensional array as say this:

```
int[][][][] c = {{1,2,3}}
```

How will you imagine that? This is because NONE of the textbooks I have read every described an array that is more than 2-D array. They will simply say, countless dimensional array exists. But I am unable to imagine them.

Please help me answer this question as clear as possible so any other user will be fully be able to grasp any multi-dimensional array simply by reading the answer.

Comment: `int[][] a = {1,2,3}` is not valid in Java!

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson22.htm, the **Multidimensional Arrays** section should help.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  Syntax corrected

Comment: I'd just like to mention that dealing with multi-dimensional arrays is rarely a good answer in Java.  A list of lists is much easier to conceive of and deal with.  Also whatever you use--encapsulate it in a class--don't be passing it around willy-nilly.. but this is a valid question... understanding features, even those you probably shouldn't use, is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your code examples is legal Java. This declaration:

```
int[][] a;
```

declares `a` to be an array of arrays of `int`. (Java does not actually have two-dimensional arrays.) You could initialize it with an array of arrays:

```
int[][] a = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```

However, you cannot initialize with `{1, 2, 3}` because `{1, 2, 3}` is an `int[]`, not an `int[][]` (that is, an "array of `int`" is not the same type as "array of array of `int`").

Similar considerations would apply to the other cases. For instance:

```
int[][][][] c;
```

declares an array of arrays of arrays of arrays of `int`.

Once you understand the basic concept of an array of arrays, it's not too hard to understand specific declarations. For instance:

```
int[][][] b = new int[3][4][2];
```

declares `b` to be an array of length 3. Each element of `b` is an array of 4 arrays, each of which is an array of 2 `int` values. As usual, all `int` values are initialized to 0. You don't have to initialize trailing dimensions:

```
int[][][] b = new int[3][][];
```

declares `b` to be an array 3 long. Each element must be an `int[][]`, but initially all elements will be `null`.

There's no requirement that the elements have the same length. So, for instance, `b[1]` might be set to an array of length 7, while `b[2]` might have length 12.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) goes into great detail about array creation.

Comment: I still did not get it! So how is 
     int[][][][] = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}}

different from your 2-D array

Comment: @user2282158 - I expanded my answer a bit. See if that addresses your question.

Comment: For your example int[][][] b = new int[3][4][2]; how is the array a length of three? Is it because it has got three square brackets?

Comment: @user2282158 - Because the first dimension in the `new` operator is 3.

Comment: Okay so for say int[][][][] d = new int[4][5][6][7], does it mean the array is of length 4, what about the other diemnsions? Can you give me a fixed rule like how you said first dimension is always the length of array, then what does it's successive dimensions have to be?

Like for your 3-D array, you said

[][][] = [length][size of each element in the array][size of the each element in the previous array] does it roll on like this?

Comment: Great, I am a beginner, so I would look at it after I finish introduction to java textbook

Comment: @user2282158 - To start, consider a 2-d array: `int[][] a = new int[4][]` would be an array 4 long, all elements of which are `null`. `int[][] a = new int[4][3]` would be an array 4 long, each element of which is an array 3 long of `int` values (all of which would be 0). For more dimensions, it just, as you say, roll on like this.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this in conjunction with @Ted Hopp's answer.

I just want to explain *why* the examples you gave are not valid Java.

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3}}
```

This is (now) valid (apart from the missing semicolon at the end)

```
int[][][] b = {{1,2,3}}
```

That is invalid because the array initializer specifies a 2-D array, and you are assigning it to a 3-D array.

```
int[][][][] c = {{1,2,3}}
```

That is invalid because the array initializer specifies a 2-D array, and you are assigning it to a 4-D array.

In fact, this should clear up your concern over what happens in those cases.  The answer is nothing.  The code is illegal.  The dimensionality of the declared array type and the initializer *must* be the same.

---

With respect to rectangular arrays (or the N-dimensional analogs) created like this.

```
int[][][][] d = new int[4][5][6][7];
```

the lengths of each of the dimensions can simply be read off the initializer; i.e. that is declaring the Java equivalent of a `4x5x6x7` 4-D matrix.  And you can do this in code too.

```
System.out.println(d.length);   // prints 4 
System.out.println(d[0].length);   // prints 5 
System.out.println(d[0][0].length);   // prints 6
System.out.println(d[0][0][0].length);   // prints 7
```

You can do this with ragged arrays too ... except that you will find that the lengths of the various subarrays are not uniform.  Rather they depend on how big the respective subarray was in the initializer, or whatever.

---

> This is because NONE of the textbooks I have read every described an array that is more than 2-D array.

In defence of the textbook authors:

1. It is unusual for real Java programs to use arrays above 2-D, and even more unusual to initialize them using `{{{...}}}` style initializers.
2. In fact, the same pattern that is used for 1-D and 2-D arrays *does* extend to higher dimensional arrays in a natural and obvious way.  (Or at least, it is natural and obvious to most Java programmers ...)

So spending extra pages of a textbook to explain something that is "obvious" AND "rarely used" is hard to justify, especially if that means cutting material out of the book in other places.

And FWIW, typical Java textbooks also fail to mention other obscure corners of the Java language, like break-to-label, initializer blocks, '$' in variable names, the Java name resolution rules and so on.  This is probably A GOOD THING<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Yea ... I've been reading "1066 and all that" again.</sup>

Comment: a more clarification how is int[] a = {{1,2,3}} different from 2D array: int[][] a = {{1,2,3}}

Comment: Thank you very much, I would just like to clear one point :
for int[4][5][6][7], you will have 4 groups. Each of the four groups is made into 4 lists. Each of these 4 lists will have 6 elements, in which each of these element is an array will have 7 elements each?

So basically, first dimension is the length and any other dimension that predates is basically the length of array in the preceding array. Yes?

Comment: The "int[] a = {{1,2,3}}" version is a compilation error for the same reason that "int[][][][] c = {{1,2,3}}" is a compilation error.  Please read my Answer again.

Comment: Your other comment is doesn't make any sense to me.  I don't know what "groups" you are talking about, or what you mean about them being made into 4 lists, or where the 6 elements come from.  You've totally baffled me.

Comment: Don't worry Stephen, I got it. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time with this concept myself when I first encountered multidimensional arrays.

First think of a 2D array as an image. Each element is a pixel.

A 3D array is then a movie. An element at [i, j, k] is the pixel at coordinates (i, j) in frame k of the movie.

A 4D array is a movie composed of multiple cameras, [i, j, k, l] is the pixel at coordinates (i, j) in the kth frame of the lth camera.

Think about multidimensional arrays like that for a while, and after a while, you will just ignore the dimensionality of it altogether.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but I got it more naturally now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Java uses jagged arrays which means array of arrays.

```
int[][] array = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

While in other languages like C#, they have multi-dimension arrays (besides the jagged arrays):

```
string[,] array = new string[2,3];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would declare and initialize 1D, 2D, 3D and 4D arrays:

```
int[] oneD = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int[][] twoD = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
int[][][] threeD = { { {1,2,3,4,5}, {2,3}, {3}}, {{4}, {5,6,6,7}, {10,6,7} } };
int[][][][] fourD = { { { {1,1}, {2}},{{1,2}, {3}}, {{3}, {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}}, {{{4},{5,6,7}}, {{5},{6}}, {{6,1,2},{0,7} } } };
```

Comment: Okay so for say int[][][][] d = new int[4][5][6][7], does it mean the array is of length 4, what about the other diemnsions? Can you give me a fixed rule like how you said first dimension is always the length of array, then what does it's successive dimensions have to be? Like for your 3-D array, you said [][][] = [length][size of each element in the array][size of the each element in the previous array] does it roll on like this?

Comment: Try to get the 3D first, then move on to 4D based on the same rules. So for an `int[4][5][6]` 3D array you will have four groups. Each of the four groups is made of five lists. Each list contains six numbers. So the 3D array will contain 4 * 5 * 6 = 120 `int`s.

Comment: So for int[4][5][6][7], you will have 4 groups. Each of the four groups is made into 4 lists. Each of these 4 lists will have 6 elements, in which each of these element is an array will have 7 elements each?

Comment: So basically, first dimension is the length and any other dimension that predates is basically the length of array in the preceding array. Yes?

Comment: Yes. To make it less confusing, you have 4 lists, each containing 5 lists, each containing 6 lists, each containing 7 numbers. :)